# GStreamer in Kinesis Video Streams C++ Producer SDK

Tags: gstreamer, amazon-kinesis

All i'm doing after ./install-script but when i run ./gstreamer-plugin-install-script this show me below error guide which i follow https://diycode.cc/projects/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp
kinesis-video-gstreamer-plugin/tst/gstkvstest.cpp:1:10: fatal error: gstkvssink.h: No such file or directory

## include "gstkvssink.h" //import this first, or will cause build error on Mac

^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/gstkvsplugintest.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/gstkvsplugintest.dir/home/saeed/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/kinesis-video-gstreamer-plugin/tst/gstkvstest.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/gstkvsplugintest.dir/home/saeed/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/kinesis-video-gstreamer-plugin/tst/gstkvstest.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/gstkvsplugintest.dir/all' failed
make[2]:**  [CMakeFiles/gstkvsplugintest.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:74: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/gstkvsplugintest.dir/rule' failed
make[1]:  **[CMakeFiles/gstkvsplugintest.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'gstkvsplugintest' failed
make: *** [gstkvsplugintest] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have opened an issue against one of the repositories.

I would recommend you to try using min_install_script first to pull down the dependencies using the platform specific package manager rather than attempting to build everything from scratch.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/blob/master/install-instructions-macos.md#build-the-kinesis-video-producer-sdk-and-sample-applications